# window.onbeforeunload support in Firefox

Tags: firefox, window, onbeforeunload

I am using window.onbeforeunload in my javascript.
This works perfectly in IE but is not triggered in Firefox.

I checked on different links in stackoverflow.... In it I read that window.onbeforeunload is not supported by firefox. Is this true?

If yes, can you please tell me a different way to call app.deleteAccount(key) on close of browser. Here is my javascript. Please look at the deleteFile() and dontDeleteFile() methods.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Event handler for body onload
function confirmDeleteFile(){
    var secured =document.r_form.Secure[1].checked;
    alert("confirmDeleteFile : "+secured);
    if(secured){
     var agree=confirm("Are you sure you wish to continue?");
     if (agree){
      //document.form1.submit();
      return true;
     }
     else
     return false ;
    }
  //  submitForm();
    return true;
   }
function deleteFile() {
 alert('inside deleteFile() but outside window.onbeforeunload');
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
 var key = DOMAIN+'::' + elem('userName').value;
alert('inside deleteFile()');
    app.deleteAccount(key)  
    alert('Unloading!');
   } 
}
function dontDeleteFile() {
 alert('inside dontDeleteFile() but outside window.onbeforeunload');
 window.onbeforeunload = function(){ 
  alert("Not deleting"); 
    } 
 }

function validateFormOnSubmit(theForm) {
var reason = "";
var userName = theForm.username.value;
var pin = theForm.pin1.value;
var PAM = theForm.pam.value;
var organization = theForm.organization.value;
//reason += validateUsername(theForm.username);
reason += validateEmpty(theForm.pam);
reason += validatePinMatch(theForm.pin1,theForm.pin2);
reason += validatePin(theForm.pin1,theForm.pin2);
if (reason != "") {
if(!confirmDeleteFile()){
 return false;
}
alert("Some fields need correction:\n" + reason);
return false;
}
else{
 if(!confirmDeleteFile()){
  return false;
 }

<% String url  =  request.getServerName().toString();
 int port = request.getServerPort();
 String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
%>
 var servlet = "arcotebank.az"; //AroctEBanking Servlet
  var url = BASE_URL + '/' + servlet;
     var query = 'lang=en&reqid=1&version=1.1';
     query += '&device=' + urlEncode(navigator.userAgent);
     query += '&uid=' + urlEncode(userName);
     query += '&code=' + urlEncode(PAM); 
     query += '&pin=' + urlEncode(pin);
     query += '&usePin=' + usePin+'&method=arcotOTPEnroll&organization='+organization; 
//alert("url=>"+url + '?' + query);
  var xml = app.openUrl(url + '?' + query) + '';
  //alert("xml=>"+xml);
  if(appError()){
    alert("applet error");
  }
var domain = getDomain(url);
app.provisionAccount(domain, xml);
  if(appError()){
    alert("applet error");
   }
var acc = app.getAccount(DOMAIN + '::' + userName);
     if(acc!=null){
     <%String formSubmitAction1 =
            URLEncoderDecoder.encodeURL(
                        formAction,
                        "Action.2FA.Arcot.Navigation.LogoutActionCalled=Y",cm);%>
                theForm.action ='<%=formSubmitAction1%>';
                var secured =document.r_form.Secure[1].checked;
               alert("line 131 "+secured);
                if(secured){
                 deleteFile();
    }else{
    dontDeleteFile();
    }               
       theForm.submit();
     }else{
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Failed to Create ArcotOTP";
     }
}
}
function resetForm(){
     var form = document.forms[0]; 
     form.username.value = '';
     form.pam.value = '';
     form.pin1.value = '';
     form.pin2.value = '';
  }
function validateUsername(fld) {
var error = "";
var illegalChars = /\W/; // allow letters, numbers, and underscores

if (fld.value == "") {
fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
error = "You didn't enter a username.\n";
} else if ((fld.value.length < 5) || (fld.value.length > 15)) {
fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
error = "The username should contain more than 4 characters.\n";
} else if (illegalChars.test(fld.value)) {
fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
error = "The username contains illegal characters.\n";
} else {
fld.style.background = 'White';
}
return error;
}
function validateEmpty(fld) {
 var error = "";

 if (fld.value.length == 0) {
 fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
 error = "You didn't enter Personal Assurance Message \n"
 } else {
 fld.style.background = 'White';
 }
 return error;
 }

function validatePin(pin1,pin2){
 var error="";

   if(pin1.value!=pin2.value){
    pin1.style.background = 'Yellow';
    pin2.style.background = 'Yellow';
    error += "Pin numbers dont match\n";
     //alert("Pin numbers dont match");

     }
     return error;

 }
 function validatePinMatch(pin1,pin2){
 var error="";
 if(pin1.value==""){
  //elem('otp').style.background = 'Yellow';
  pin1.style.background = 'Yellow';
  error += "Pin number cannot be empty\n";
  //alert("Pin number cannot be empty");

  }
 if(pin2.value==""){
  //elem('otp').style.background = 'Yellow';
     pin2.style.background = 'Yellow';
  error += "Confirm Pin number cannot be empty\n";
  //alert("Pin number cannot be empty");

  }
  return error;
 }

</script>
```

Comment: sorry... the code lost its formatting

Comment: Plz neglect the previous comment

Answer (score 3):

> Note that in Firefox 4 and later the returned string is not displayed to the user. See Bug 588292.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

Maybe this is what's causing your problem in part. Also the example on the page might be better suited for cross-browser compatibility?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var e = e || window.event;

  // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Any string';
  }

  // For Safari
  return 'Any string';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

window.onbeforeunload is supported by Firefox and all major browsers. It should be implemented as a function that returns a string, which will be used as the message in the confirmation dialog.

Comment: Can you tell me why its not getting invoked in my code snippet

Comment: Also ... can you please tell me if its supported in Google Chrome and opera??

Comment: See my edited answer. onbeforeunload is supported in all major browsers. You should return a string from the implementation of the function.

Comment: Is it possible to call a applet function from it?? Like in the deleteFile() method of my code i have called app.deleteAccount(key)... This is the applet method. Its not getting called in firefox. Works fine in IE

Comment: First test that you can call the applet method in another function. If this is possible, then it probably has to do with the Java plug-in in Firefox. If you have access to the Java code, it will be better to handle this situation there.