# Mozilla firefox not working with window.onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, dom-events, onbeforeunload

I'm using `window.onbeforeunload` to display a message to the user on windows close, the function works well with Chrome and IE but it doesn't work with Firefox, I'm using Firefox version `26.0` I have tried many but with no mean, somebody said that its a bug in Firefox as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727216/window-onbeforeunload-support-in-firefox)  and another suggests some solutions as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645011/window-onbeforeunload-and-window-onunload-is-not-working-in-firefox-safari-o) I tried all the solutions available using Javascript and jQuery but it doesn't work, now I display a confirm dialog but the browser default dialog appears after it and I'm not satisfied with that, I tried also to prevent the browser default dialog from appearing using `preventDefault()` but also with no mean! if there's any solution to this problem it will be great, here's how I used the `window.onbeforeunload`:

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = confirmWinClose();
function confirmWinClose() {
     var myVar ='${isFireFox}';
     if(myVar=='true'){
         return confirm(confirmExamClose);
     }else{
         return confirmExamClose;
     }

}
<script>
```

Note:`isFireFox` is a jsp variable that I used to know the type of the browser using `User-Agent` Header and `confirmExamClose` is the message that I display to the user.

Answer (score 15):

Here is working solution for Firefox and Chrome. I haven't yet tested in Safari and Opera.

```
var myEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload'; /// make IE7, IE8 compitable

myEvent(chkevent, function(e) { // For >=IE7, Chrome, Firefox
    var confirmationMessage = 'Are you sure to leave the page?';
    (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;
    return confirmationMessage;
});
```

Comment: although this works, the confirmation message is not showing on firefox. off to look for way to do this...

Comment: it's firfox behavior @Jim, firefox doesn't allow to show custom message.

Comment: @faisale i dont want to shoq confirmation msg, how can i achieve this?

Comment: I don't get it, above code is to show confirmation message, if you don't want to show it then commented out the above code in you html.

Answer (score 5):

I looked for a Firefox `onbeforeunload` solution over 2 days and with no luck, so I worked hard on this, and did it with a little trick.

In my trick, the user needs to click on the browser window at least once.
If the user clicks on the window and then clicks on the back button, refreshes the page, or tries to exit the page, `onbeforeunload` events will fire,

```js
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    return "Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
});
$(window).one('click',function(){
    alert('hi');
    $('.javavoid').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
.hide{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <a class="hide javavoid" href="javascript:void(0)">asdf</a>
    <p>Welcome, click anywhere then click on back button or refresh page</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Note that in FF 115 it worked only if the previous page had different origin. If the origin is same in both previous and next page (say localhost:3000 to localhost:3000), you won't see the message while going back.

Answer (score 4):

Using the code given in the MDN works for me in firefox/chrome/IE11 (haven't try other browser for now).

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var e = e || window.event;

  // For IE and Firefox
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Any string';
  }

  // For Safari
  return 'Any string';
};
```

here is the doc : [Mdn window.onbeforeunload doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Answer (score -1):

Why are you doing browser-sniffing here?  The "Firefox" branch of your code is returning the return value of `window.confirm`, which is a boolean.  But a boolean isn't callable, so assigning it to `window.onbeforeunload` is the same as assigning null.

What you probably want to do is remove the browser-sniffing and just do:

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExamClose;
```

Comment: Running the handler works fine.  Posing dialogs from beforeunload handlers (apart from by returning false) is no longer allowed because too many sites were abusing that.