# beforeunload function is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The following function is working in Chrome and Internet Explorer but not in Mozilla Firefox, why is that ?

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () 
{
   if (document.getElementById('flg').value != 'ServiceSucceeded') 
   {
      document.getElementById('flg').value = '1';
      noBack();
   }
 });
```

Comment: check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773306/mozilla-firefox-not-working-with-window-onbeforeunload

Comment: $ is of jquery have you included jquery?

Comment: yes i included jquery

Comment: no its not working i tried that

Comment: do u have any solution