# Javascript: onUnload event not working

Tags: javascript, onunload

I can't get the bit of JavaScript code. Was watching a tutorial on JavaScript so I tested it my self. I went to read up a bit and some sources said it did not work in Chrome so I tested with Firefox. However, it still did not work on Firefox. What went wrong?

```
    <body onUnload="alert('Good Bye!');"></body>
```

UPDATE: By the way, the person in the tutorial used

```
    <body onUnload="alert('Good bye');"></body>
```

and it worked for him. He was using a older version of Chrome.

Comment: I also tested with Firefox and it didn't work.

Comment: take a look, he said it didn't work on FF as we expected. He already knows about chrome. :/

Comment: Try this fiddle in IE:http://jsfiddle.net/v5FLp/

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773306/mozilla-firefox-not-working-with-window-onbeforeunload

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=391834 Maybe the tutorial is years old.

Comment: @user3744056, if the answer below solved your problem then pleas mark it as accepted. Otherwise adding your own solution as the accepted answer can help others with a similar problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try OnBeforeUnload, unless you're targeting older browsers.

Comment: You'll have to find someone to do some testing for you. I only develop for the latest versions of Ch, FF, OP, and SF. IE I sometimes support as far back as 8.