# Close child window on f5 refresh

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code that launches another page in an external window.

```
var myOpenWindow = window.open(...);
```

I manage this window throughout the applications life cycle and once the forum is completed my managing state closes this window.

However, the issue I am facing is that if the user hits `f5` for a hard refresh the window is still open after the main page loads.

At first I thought I could override the `window.open` to track the state of open windows from my app in a global variable. However, I overlooked the fact that on an `f5` reset my global is lost.

This seems like a simple problem, but the solution has evaded me. Is there anyway to close a window opened by `window.open` when the parent is refreshed?

Comment: You should be able to use the unload event. See eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324954/close-all-child-windows-when-parent-window-is-closed

Comment: you could store your global variable in a cookie or storage instead of closing the window

Comment: Try to use a modal window, from bootstrap. It will close whenever you close or reload page

Comment: Or you can change `myOpenWindow` variable with child page script when the parent page reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myOpenWindow = window.open(...);
window.onunload = function(){myOpenWindow.close()};
```

or better

```
window.addEventListener('unload',function(){myOpenWindow.close()})
```

should do that.

[MDN: WindowEventHandlers.onunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload)

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a `DIV` and place it in the center of the screen.  Add some [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to) magic and you don't have to worry about popups or blockers or other stuff.

Comment: I would prefer to do this in a `JQuery.dialog`, its just not an option at work.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the window open, with the following code :

When you reload the parent page, the child will change the `myOpenWindow` when parent page will be loaded.

Parent window :

```
function detectChild(child) {
    myOpenWindow = child;
    //opener.actionWhenOpen();
}

var myOpenWindow = window.open(...);

window.onunload = function() {
    if (myOpenWindow) {
        myOpenWindow.refreshParent();
    }
};
```

Child windows :

```
if (opener) {
    //opener.actionWhenOpen();
    opener.onunload = function() {
        if (opener && opener.myOpenWindow) {
            opener.myOpenWindow.refreshParent();
        }
    };
}

function refreshParent() {
    this.i = ((this.i) ? this.i : 0)+1;
    var i = this.i;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!opener) {
            return console.log("Opener closed.");
        } else if (opener.detectChild && !opener.myOpenWindow) {
            this.i = 0;
            opener.detectChild(window);
        } else if (i < 900) {
            console.log("Opener cheked("+i+").");
            refreshParent(i++);
        }
    }, 50);
}
```