# onbeforeunload does not work with Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, firefox

I needed to pop up a message on the event of closing the browser.I got many solutions in this site.Though the following code is suggested and verified , it works with Chrome and Opera but does not work with Firefox. Is there anything i am missing in execution ? 
Need Help. Thanks in Advance

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
var message = "Message to Show",
e = e || window.event;

if (e) {
e.returnValue = message;
}

return message;
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21456013/753537)?

Comment: Yes. But no result in Firefox

Comment: I dont think Firefox allows custom messages like this

Comment: What is the solution then ? How can i pop up a message ?

Comment: `In Firefox 4 and later the returned string is not displayed to the user. Instead, Firefox displays the string "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved."` https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588292

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload might be worth a read