# window.onbeforeunload is not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Dear friends I have an issue while trying to catch `window.onbeforeunload` event in Firefox (version. 47 and more).

The problem is that in Firefox `window.onbeforeunload` works well when I right click on screen and inside the pop-up menu choose "Reload" option.
Whereas it's not working when I:

- press `F5` or `Ctrl + F5` key
- click on the `Reload` button in browser's navigation

Here is my code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
     e = e || window.event;
     self.video_disconnect();

     if (e) {
        e.returnValue = 'Sure?';
     }

     // For Safari
     return 'Sure?';
};
```

By the way, I applied many solutions (also from here: [window.onbeforeunload and window.onunload is not working in Firefox , Safari , Opera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645011/window-onbeforeunload-and-window-onunload-is-not-working-in-firefox-safari-o) and from here: [Mozilla firefox not working with window.onbeforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773306/mozilla-firefox-not-working-with-window-onbeforeunload) ) and have searched a lot, but still could not find the appropriate one.
The solutions provided there seems old so I hope there is already new approach for this issue.
Thanks!

Comment: I used the solution provided there but it does not works for some cases.

Comment: Check the `note (2)` there regarding firefox.

Comment: which one is that?

Comment: are you about this?  - In Firefox you MUST do some real interaction with the page in order for this message to appear to the user.

Comment: Yes, exactly this.

Comment: could you ne more specific? what means real interactions? any examples?

Comment: If you will not click inside the page - the `onbeforeunload` function will do nothing. You must do some real-user-interaction with the page (if you just enter the page, and then do a refresh (f5/ctrl+f5) - the `onbeforeunload` function **will not** be called).

Comment: Does it gives you the answer you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will check a bit later and will let you know. By the way you could write your answer below.

Comment: This question is exactly the same as one I already answered, so you can vote-up the other answer (trying to prevent duplicate questions).

Comment: Thanks, your answer was helpfull.