# Run function when Page Exit

Tags: javascript, html

I can't alert or can't do anything with this code. I want to run a function when f5 or exit page but firefox always return this messages: "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved". How to fix this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Close this window, press F5 or click on the link below to invoke the onbeforeunload event.</p>

<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Click here to go to w3schools.com</a>
      
<script>

  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit(){
    alert("confirm exit is being called");
    return false;
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not c# code.

Comment: If use C# code can resolve it I very happy to accept

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/276739/405481

Comment: I tested all of these but nothing change. I still can't run alert() or any function when page exit

Comment: I find a trig for temporary resolve here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773306/mozilla-firefox-not-working-with-window-onbeforeunload

Comment: But I found new problem. When you load page at first time, this code doesn't work if you exit page but don't click link

Comment: You cannot prevent the alert when leaving the page. It's built-in browser behavior.

Comment: Did you test my comment?