# How to Execute query only when user click to cofirm on Leave option.otherwise query should not be execute

Tags: php, ajax, onbeforeunload

**That is my code**

```
function myfoo(){
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
              on_timeout: 1
            },
            success: function (r) {}
       });
    }

     window.onbeforeunload = function(){
          myfoo();
          return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
     };
```

**my update.php code:**

```
session_start(); 
include 'conn.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['Seats'])) {
    $seatS=$_SESSION['Seats']; 
    $Eventid=$_SESSION['Eventid'];
    $cats = explode(" ", $seatS); 
    $cats = preg_split('/,/', $seatS, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); 
    foreach($cats as $key => $cat ){ 
        $cat = mysql_real_escape_string($cats[$key]); 
        $cat = trim($cat);
        if($cat !=NULL) { 
            $stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE fistevent SET Status=" " where Event_Id=? AND seats="'.$cat.'" AND Status="Hold" '); 
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['Eventid']); 
            $stmt->execute(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try below `beforeunload` binding:**

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
   return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});
$(window).on('unload', function () {
   console.log('calling ajax');
   myfoo();
});
```

Comment: not working sir.now It Does not show any alert message.means leave or stay

Comment: are you getting any confirm box? with ok and cancel option?

It will execute function only when you click on ok button

Comment: my above code is running condition.. and it is also showing leave or stay alert. but when iam click on close browser it execute the query direct.but i want to execute query when click onto leave button

Comment: @krishna as i understood when user clicks on close tab of the browser the alert box must be executed. i'm i right

Comment: sir i know above code is perfect.but please try my code on your localhost.what is the problem in it

Comment: @PavanBaddi the code showing alert message .but when i click on close button it directly execute the query.

Comment: @PavanBaddi i want to execute query when click onto leave button

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan sir now showing alert message but not updating the records on confirm to leave

Comment: @krishna it should work, ok try reloading the page and check when you click on reload button then ajax is loading? check browser console, it will console log message before calling ajax

Comment: my update.php code......session_start();
include 'conn.php';if(isset($_SESSION['Seats']))
{$seatS=$_SESSION['Seats'];
      $Eventid=$_SESSION['Eventid'];$cats = explode(" ", $seatS);
     $cats = preg_split('/,/', $seatS, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
  foreach($cats as $key => $cat ){
  $cat  = mysql_real_escape_string($cats[$key]);
  $cat = trim($cat);if($cat !=NULL)
    {  $stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE fistevent SET `Status`=" " where `Event_Id`=? AND `seats`="'.$cat.'" AND `Status`="Hold" ');
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['Eventid']);
                 $stmt->execute();
    }}}

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan sir. can you tell me please why firefox not supporting this means unload and beforeunload ?on firefox it shows nothing even any alert, but  on chrome it is working

Comment: @krishna change `beforeunload` to `onbeforeunload` and check in firefox

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773306/mozilla-firefox-not-working-with-window-onbeforeunload#35484886) answer for firefox issue, and run code snippet in firefox, he is saying that user should click first on document

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan sir .don't understand what they are  trying to do. what i need to do in my code?

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan yes sir it is working and showing leave stay message  but did not updating records like in chrome