# Ajax call on onbeforeunload event doesn't work (Firefox only)

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, event-handling, onbeforeunload

I need to make an Ajax call when a user leaves my page.
I don't need to wait for the end of the call, I just need to notify my server with a kindly "hey, user XXX is leaving the page", without notifying the client.

Here is what I've done so far :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myURL,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ xxx: xxx, yyy: yyy })
    });
}
```

This perfectly works with Chrome and Edge, but this event is not raised on Firefox.

What I've done so far :

- I tried this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21456013/2687153), as the author claims it works and has a good score, but once again, my ajax call is not fired.
- Add `async: false` without any success
- Also tried to use `beforeunload` instead of `onbeforeunload`

Can anyone explain me how to fire my Ajax call when an user leaves a page, no matter he uses Chrome, Edge or Firefox ?
Thanks in advance ?

Comment: There is no way to guarantee the call will make it.

Comment: The page unload process will abort the request, if it isn't responsed within a couple of nanoseconds. You can't do anything asynchronous reliably in (before)unload listeners. Use `navigator.beacon` or a synchronous call in older browsers.